# Determining who a task is assigned to in sharepoint

Tags: javascript, sharepoint

I'm trying to figure out how to best determine to whom a task is assigned to in sharepoint. I've tried `SP.listitem.get_item('AssignedTo')"` and `parentTaskItem.get_item('AssignedTo'))`but neither seemed to do anything (or even work)

Comment: i think you can get information in created field

Answer (score 0):

You can go direct to the object:

```
listItem.get_item("AssignedTo")[0]["$5O_1"]  // will display full name but very unsafe
```

But this is better and also safer:

```
var user = listItem.get_item("AssignedTo");   // load to a var for further checking

if ( user[0] != "" ) ....
{
    console.log(user[0].get_lookupValue()); // returns full name: "John Doe"
    console.log(user[0].get_lookupId());    // returns the user ID: 11
    console.log(user[0].get_email());       // returns "john.doe@nowhere.com"
}
```

And this is the Microsoft way (right way of doing things):

```
var web = SP.ClientContext.get_current().get_web();
var user = web.getUserById(listItem.get_item("AssignedTo")); // from here you get lots of methods like the above, but this call needs to be async
```